# MySQL access denied

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL, but it says access denied. Does anyone know what to do? I'm doing this on a macbook.

```
  mysql> \q
    Bye
    Stefans-Air:bin stefansudu$ ./mysqladmin -u root password 'root'
    mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
    error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Comment: welcome to the site. It is authentication error.

Comment: thanks, do you know what i need to do? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is an authentication error. You can debug this issue by following the below steps:

- First check the **host name**. Are you mentioned the correct hostname?
- Check MySQL running on the mentioned host. If not running, **start the service** and trying to connect.
- If MySQL service is running and still, if you are not able to connect, check whether you are giving the **right password**.
- If password is right, check whether the **user have access** from the mentioned host. If not, please **grant access** to that user.
- If you **forget the password**, please try to reset the password. [Click here](https://debian-administration.org/article/442/Resetting_a_forgotten_MySQL_root_password) for reference.
- Still, if you are getting the same error, [Click here](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/04/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-user-host-using-password-YES.html) to see other possible workarounds.

I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your MySQL server's root account has a password, but you are not using one to authenticate.

If you want to change the password of the user "root", use the following command:

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p"current-password" password "new-password"
```

If you just want to connect to mysqladmin, use the following syntax. Of course you need to replace "command" by something valid like "status".

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p"current-password" command
```

Comment: do i need go out from the bin?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm very new to this, shall i quit terminal and start again? or should i stay in the bin?

Comment: At first you should make clear what you want to do. If you want to call mysqladmin somehow, do it as before, but with the adjusted parameters I described.